# How to apply kubernetes DaemonSet using Terraform in Google Cloud

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, terraform

I'm create k8s in Google Cloud using Terraform, several node pools contains GPU, according [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/gpus) there should be applied DaemonSet with GPU drivers. It's possible to do it with Terraform or this operation requires my attention?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you looked at https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/kubernetes/r/daemonset.html ?

Comment: @ydaetskcoR with this I should convert [this yaml](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/container-engine-accelerators/master/nvidia-driver-installer/cos/daemonset-preloaded.yaml) to Terraform template. May be there is another possibility?

Comment: note that if you are using GKE, the daemonset is created automatically, you do not need to create one

Comment: Are you using GKE or GCE for Your k8s cluster?

Comment: @PiotrMalec, I use GKE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Patric W and Google Cloud [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/gpus#installing_drivers) mentioned:

> After adding GPU nodes to your cluster, you need to install NVIDIA's device drivers to the nodes. Google provides a DaemonSet that automatically installs the drivers for you.

So all We have to do is to apply [DaemonSet](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/container-engine-accelerators/master/nvidia-driver-installer/ubuntu/daemonset-preloaded.yaml) provided by Google.

For Container-Optimized OS (COS) nodes:

```
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/container-engine-accelerators/master/nvidia-driver-installer/cos/daemonset-preloaded.yaml
```

For Ubuntu Nodes:

```
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/container-engine-accelerators/master/nvidia-driver-installer/ubuntu/daemonset-preloaded.yaml
```

---

Based on Terraform [documentation](https://www.terraform.io/docs/provisioners/local-exec.html) You can use `provisioner "local-exec"` to run kubectl apply command for DaemonSet after successful cluster deployment.

```
provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/container-engine-accelerators/master/nvidia-driver-installer/cos/daemonset-preloaded.yaml"
  }
}
```

Note that example above is for COS node version.

Comment: One may have to worry that the kubectl is pointing at a different cluster than the one being provisioned by terraform.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is converting it into HCL language. This did the job for me [k2tf](https://github.com/sl1pm4t/k2tf) for this particular use case and worked nicely